# Cannot get object MsLoader in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm using MultiSeller extension in my opencart. It worked before. But it didn't work now, displaying with this error in my page: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in`. I checked my code according to the error message, it refer to this line `$this->MsLoader->MsSeller->`.

I tried to echo `$this` to my page, and I didn't find the MsLoader object.

Anyone knows what's going on here?

PS. I installed a MyCnCart blog to my opencart, not sure if this has something impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the cause. Someone installed the extension by replacing the admin and catalog folder using vqmod, which is different from installing from admin console. So the vqmod didn't override the correct one. After I changed the path in vqmod it actually refers to, it works.

```
file name="system/modification/system/engine/loader.php"
```

This is the old one:

```
system/engine/loader.php
```

Hope this will help anyone who encounters this issue.